# Excel set range have date as variant

Tags: excel, date, variant, vba

I have this code. When I set `rDate = Range("A14"),`excel always understand that rDate as a value not a date`.`Example`if I set rDate as specific time (like 04/04/2017), iVal is 6.`But if I setrDate = Range("A14"), ival = 0 `(Column F contain dates and Range("A14") = 04/04/2017). How can I set rDate as date?

```
Dim rDate As Range
Set rDate = Range("A14")
iLastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("F1:F" & iLastrow), rDate)
Sheets(1).Activate
Range("C14").Value = iVal
```

Comment: Your code (after the edit which invalidates my answer) should work.  Please advise what it is doing that isn't what is expected.

Comment: Does cell `A14` contain a date?  Do cells `F1:F..` contain dates?  And what do you mean by "Excel always understand that rDate as a value not a date"?

Comment: Yes. F1:F contain dates and nd range("A14") contain date also. I want to count date in column F contain date in cell A14

Comment: What happens if you try `Debug.Print rDate.Address` ? There is a good chance your issue is simply to do with not qualifying your ranges properly. You have already demonstrated that the `CountIf` works with a specific value.

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie Thank your advance. When I try `Debug.Print rDate.Address` , the rusult is `$A$14`

Comment: Check out the code in answer by @ShaiRado below - this is a great example of qualifying ranges properly.

Comment: If both `A14` and `F1:F..` contain dates, then the code will work.  I suspect that one of the two ranges contains something that looks like a date but is actually text.  Try changing the formats of both areas to "General".  If the contents still look like a date then the contents of the cells are actually text.

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks. I found my mistake

Comment: So was the mistake that you had text instead of dates?  Or was it something else?  (It helps if we know, so that we can answer other similar questions.)

Comment: @YowE3K Yes. The mistake that  format is text

Comment: That's one of the most common causes of "date" problems.  Excel tends to make it very hard to tell whether a cell contains a real date or just text that looks like a date, and it doesn't make it easy to compare the two.  I'm glad the problem is now sorted out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below (explanation in the code comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub CountIfDates()

Dim rDateRng    As Range
Dim rDate       As Double
Dim iLastrow    As Long
Dim iVal        As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
    Set rDateRng = .Range("A14")
    rDate = rDateRng.Value ' <-- get the date value and store the the numeric value

    iLastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("F1:F" & iLastrow), rDate)
End With

Sheets(1).Range("C14").Value = iVal

End Sub
```